# Magento frontend and backend CSS is not working

Tags: magento2, php, javascript, css

I have installed Magento 2.2.5 on my server using Cpanel. The problem I am facing is my CSS is not working properly. The Url of my site is http://emcd.tk/. I've looked on so many solutions but didn't find any proper one. I also attached the picture showing errors.

[image]

**Things I've tried so far:**

1. Giviving permission for var & pub folders.
2. php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
3. Do reindex php bin/magento indexer:reindex
4. Clearing cache using commands [php bin/magento cache:clean] and [php bin/magento cache:flush]

The reason of doing this if you take the source code and check, the CSS & JS file path may wrong. So that the style won’t render in a browser even I tried to make it correct but didn't work properly.

I would appreciate any kind of help. Thank you

Comment: Are you able to access admin properly ?

Comment: yes i can and i can also able to login in it but without css just like my hompage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issues is resolved. After checking apache error logs, it was throwing the following error:

```
Invalid command '<IfVersion', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration.
```

So after installing `mod_version` into apache, the site is no longer throwing the error and working fine now.

**Note:** Special thanks to Cpanel for helping.

Answer (score 1):

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

and check memory-limits (1024M) in php configuration

Add code
/etc/apache2/apache2.conf :

Comment: I cannot directly edit the .conf file as it will be overwritten by cPanel update or account level modification.

Comment: try to edit file this way
https://askubuntu.com/questions/890672/all-i-want-to-do-is-edit-a-file-but

Comment: thank  you its works. I was faced issue duringh access magento via Ip address. So i tried your solution

Comment: can you post another way for access magento via ip address in ubuntu apache server?

Answer (score 0):

It has happened to me several times. This must be some kind of installation/compilation or deployment.

Try and run this command:

```
rm -rf pub/static/*; php bin/magento setup:upgrade; 
php bin/magento setup:di:compile; php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy;
```

If it doesn't work after this, you should try re-installing.

Comment: Thanks much appreciate, i tried as u describe but didn't change anything even i also re-install but still same

Comment: Can you try applying another theme? As far as I see you have now magento Luma, can you try magento Blank?

Answer (score 0):

1) Fire below query

```
`INSERT INTO `core_config_data`(`path`, `value`) VALUES ('dev/static/sign', 0) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `value`=0`
```

2. sudo php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
3. sudo chmod 777 -R var/ pub/ generated.
4. Clear your browser and Magento cache and check it.

Comment: didnt work for me ..

Comment: Please check if there is .htaccess file under pub/static folder.

Comment: yes there is .haccess file under pub/static folder.

Answer (score 0):

I think You are missing `.htaccess` file in your `pub/static` folder

download below file

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2.5/pub/static/.htaccess

and put this file in your `pub/static` folder and  hard refresh your browser

Comment: Thanks. I've tried but didn't work

Answer (score 0):

We have also faced the same issue in order to resolve this follow the below steps:

1. navigate to root directory of you magento2 installation
2. Remove existing static content: `rm -R pub/static/*`
3. Run: `php bin/magento setup:upgrade;`
4. Run: `php bin/magento setup:di:compile;`
5. Then deploy static files content forcefully with this command: `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f`
6. Do reindex `php bin/magento indexer:reindex`
7. Once you do this make sure to give all the files permission to 755 with `sudo chmod 755 . -R`
8. Then give permission to web user with this command `sudo chown www-data:www-data . -R`

Hope if works for you

Comment: Thank you for replying I've tried it so many times but situation is still same

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Linux OS Please run below command:

s1. sudo a2enmod ssl

s2. sudo a2ensite default-ssl

s3. sudo a2enmod rewrite

s4. sudo service apache2 restart

Answer (score 0):

New apache version has change in some way. If your apache version is 2.4 then you have to go to /etc/apache2/. There will be a file named apache2.conf. You have to edit that one(you should have root permission). Change directory text like this

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Now restart apache.

```
sudo service apache2 reload
```

Hope it works.